# Golang http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls

Tags: forms, web, go

So I am currently writing a login and respectively a signup features for my Go web App and I am attempting to implement a feature that if you don't fill out both the required form fields "username" "password" it will give you an `http.Error` and then I am attempting to make it `http.Redirect` yet i get this error when redirecting occurs. `http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls` Here is my code..

```
//Check form submission
var u user
if req.Method == http.MethodPost {
    un := req.FormValue("username")
    p := req.FormValue("password")


    //Checking to see if user filled out required fields.
    if un == ""{
        http.Error(w, "Please fill out required fields, you will be redirected shortly.", http.StatusForbidden)
        time.Sleep(3000 * time.Millisecond)
        //http.Redirect(w, req, "/" http.StatusSeeOther)
        return

    }else if p == "" {
        http.Error(w, "Please fill out required fields, you will be redirected shortly.", http.StatusForbidden)
        time.Sleep(3000 * time.Millisecond)
        //http.Redirect(w, req, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
        return
    }

    c.Value = un
    u = user{un, p}

    dbUsers[c.Value] = u
    http.Redirect(w, req, "/login", http.StatusSeeOther)

    log.Println(dbUsers)
    return
}
```

I do know that it is because of the multiple http calls within the if/else statement yet I can't quite come up with an alternative. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show all of the request handler.  The other header write is coming from code we cannot see.

Comment: You cannot call `http.Error` and then `http.Redirect` which is likely the source of your error. I'm not sure if you commented it out for this post intentionally though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not send multiple responses to the same request (first the validation error (403 but 400 would be better) and then the redirection (301, ...)).

You could use a meta tag or javascript to redirect on the client side after an delay or directly use the http redirect, like

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=https://your.site/">
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up adding another gohtml template and adding this code so that when a user wrongfully fills out a form, they are redirected to the "forbidden.gohtml" page. Given the error message and redirected back. Thank you very much!